# chkdsk An unspecified error occured (6c6f6766696c652e 2a9)

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, hardware-failure, chkdsk

I ran the chkdsk /f command for my external Toshiba 2TB hard drive. It ran the first two stages just fine. However, gave an error at the 3rd Stage. Following is the output log from chkdsk at Stage 3 via event viewer. Can anyone tell me what this error is and how to resolve it? Note: I am using Windows 10

Thanks,

```
Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
  2465 reparse records processed.
  182062 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
CHKDSK is scanning unindexed files for reconnect to their original directory.
Recovering orphaned file 205A10~1.JPG (16D4) into directory file 1671.
Recovering orphaned file 2014-03-01 11.46.22.jpg (16D4) into directory file 1671.
  4 unindexed files scanned.
  1 unindexed files recovered to original directory.
CHKDSK is recovering remaining unindexed files.
  3 unindexed files recovered to lost and found.
    Lost and found is located at \found.004

  2465 reparse records processed.

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
Security descriptor verification completed.
  8727 data files processed.
A disk read error occurredc0000010
An unspecified error occurred (6c6f6766696c652e 2a9).
```

**Edit:**
Following is the SMART report via CMD:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>wmic diskdrive get status, model, mediatype
MediaType                 Model                                Status
External hard disk media  TOSHIBA External USB 3.0 USB Device  OK
Fixed hard disk media     ST500DM002-1BD142                    OK
```

I have also included a more detailed report via CrystalDiskInfo. I couldn't embed it so I have included it as a link. In summary it shows the Health status as 'Caution'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cv3BH.png)

Comment: Your disk may be failing. Have you run a SMART report?

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for the reply. I have included the SMART report now. And it shows 'OK'

Comment: Where is the rest of the report?

Comment: @Danish366 - Based on the disk read error I wouldn't trust that status.

Comment: @DavidPostill That is all I got. I ran it via command prompt.

Comment: I have included a more detailed report via CrystalDiskInfo. I wouldn't allow me to embed it in post so I have included it as a link.